# How can I add leave counter in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, laravel-blade

I have 2 columns medical and casual leave, I have 2 medical leaves in my database , So i want count of that to leaves, instead of that it displays me 1 1, How can I resolve that?

here is my code of view file

```
<td>
@foreach($employeeLeave as $empleave)
@if($empName['personal_detail']['first_name'] == $empleave->name)
   @if($empleave->type == 'casual')
      {{ count([$empleave->type]) }}
   @endif
@endif
@endforeach
</td>
<td>
@foreach($employeeLeave as $empleave)
@if($empName['personal_detail']['first_name'] == $empleave->name)
   @if($empleave->type == 'medical')
      {{ count([$empleave->type]) }}
   @endif
@endif
@endforeach
</td>
```

Comment: Try it `count($employeeLeave)`

Comment: Nope it disaplys 2 times 4 like 4 4

Comment: It means that your `$employeeLeave` array contains 4 values instead of 2

Comment: yes 1 casual leave and 3 medical leaves but one employee take 2 medical leaves so there I want to display 2, but it disaply 1 1

Comment: @amindevloper you can get the count using `$employeeLeave->where('type', 'medical')->count()`.

Comment: Nope, it disaplys 3 3, displays digit 2 times

Comment: @amindevloper because you are using loop, remove the loop and you can get it correct.

Comment: thanks but @RahulMeshram Solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like counting in loops at first and then populating

```
@php
$casualCount = $medicalCount = 0;
@endphp
@foreach($employeeLeave as $empleave)
   @if($empName['personal_detail']['first_name'] == $empleave->name)
        @if($empleave->type == 'casual')
             @php $casualCount++; @endphp
        @endif
        @if($empleave->type == 'medical')
            @php $medicalCount++; @endphp
        @endif
   @endif
@endforeach
```

And then your html

```
<td>
{{ $casualCount }}
</td>

<td>
{{ $medicalCount }}
</td>
```

Comment: Is it correct to using loop to count this? this should be done on query level.

Comment: No. But I am going into flow of requirement of OP.

Comment: yeah of course, thank you so much it works, perfectly, Tysm @RahulMeshram

Comment: Will you please help me, how can I short those dates with month and year like, If i select month april than it have to give me results of employee who take leave in april same for other months

Comment: Post a new question on SO \and send link in here. I will try to solve, but without any data and piller, I can't help you out.

Comment: What mate? You removed your old question? No!!! You should post new one. Understand!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/327048/how-can-i-make-attandance-module-of-employee-in-laravel

Comment: Sorry sir I post old question as it is, sent link of new one, I am doing old one as it is

Comment: I have updated the question as it was, will you please help me in this new one?

Comment: Checking. Hang on a moment

Comment: Thank You!! Thankq so much Sir

Comment: Oh freaaa. Have you removed question? Can't you post it on StackOverflow not metastackexchange?

Comment: Actually I have to put tags on that and as a begineear I dont have much reputation so they dont allow me, and they deleted it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55760984/how-can-i-count-month-wise-present-day-in-laravel
Here is my question